# Outlook Calendar in shared group creates duplicates of events

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-office-2016

We have following issue in Office 365 (current version: 2016)

We share a group for mailing purposes. Because our responsibility for this group is rotated we tried to create an calendar for this, just holding the information who is responsible this week.

First I thought about creating a separate calendar and share this one. But then we found out, that the group contains already a shared calendar. So we decided to use this one.

Unfortunately, for every event in the shared group calendar a mail message is processed to the group, and so to every member of the group. As result of this, the event is copied to the private calendar of every member. 
But this is quite a mess, because now everyone has permanently entries in the calendar which shouldn't be there.

Is there a possibility to change the behavior in a way this mess is avoided?
So we can share the group calendar, but don't get copies of the events in our private calendar

Comment: I have the same issue, kind of defeats the purpose of the shared calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like to answer my one question. But to close this question I will do it:

The only suitable way I found was, to create an separate calendar, which is not directly linked to the group. And share it with the people from the group!

Sure it is not what I was asking for, but the best way I found